# Do sets with transparant comparators need to form an equivalence class?

Tags: c++, set, binary-search-tree

Say I have a set with a comparator like this:

```cpp
struct prefix_comparator {
    using is_transparent = void;
    struct prefix {
        std::string_view of;
    };
    bool operator()(std::string_view l, std::string_view r) const {
        return l < r;
    }
    bool operator()(std::string_view l, prefix r) const {
        // Only compare up to the size of the prefix
        auto result = l.compare(0, r.of.length(), r.of);
        return result < 0;
    }
    bool operator()(prefix l, std::string_view r) const {
        auto result = r.compare(0, l.of.length(), l.of);
        return result > 0;
    }
};
```

([Full example usage](https://godbolt.org/z/Ydo1a5PPh))

So `prefix_comparator::prefix{ "XYZ" }` compares equivalent to any string starting with `"XYZ"` with this comparator. Would it be UB to use this in a `std::set`?

It does not form equivalence classes with things of type `prefix_comparator::prefix`, since `prefix` objects cannot be compared with each other and stuff like `equiv("XYZABC", prefix{ "XYZ" }) && equiv(prefix{ "XYZ" }, "XYZabc")` but not `equiv("XYZABC", "XYZabc")`. But the set doesn't store `prefix` objects, so I don't know if this applies.

It seems to work fine in practice (with libstdc++ `std::set`): `count()` returns the correct value greater than `1`, `equal_range` can return an iterator range larger than one element, etc. I'm unsure if `find` is usable since it only returns an iterator to a single element (possibly it only returns an arbitrary element?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/associative.reqmts.general).

## [associative.reqmts.general]/24.2.7.1

> Each associative container is parameterized on Key and an ordering relation Compare that induces a strict weak ordering ([alg.sorting]) on elements of Key.

there is no "top level" requirement that non-`Key` type elements are strict weak ordered.

There are restrictions on methods and what the arguments are.  Here is the common set used:

> (7.20) `kl` is a value such that a is partitioned ([alg.sorting]) with respect to `c(x, kl)`, with `x` the key value of `e` and `e` in `a`;

> (7.21) `ku` is a value such that a is partitioned with respect to `!c(ku, x)`, with `x` the key value of `e` and `e` in `a`;

> (7.22) `ke` is a value such that a is partitioned with respect to `c(x, ke)` and `!c(ke, x)`, with `c(x, ke)` implying `!c(ke, x)` and with `x` the key value of `e` and `e` in `a`;

> (7.23) `kx` is a value such that

> (7.23.1) `a` is partitioned with respect to `c(x, kx)` and `!c(kx, x)`, with `c(x, kx)` implying `!c(kx, x)` and with `x` the key value of `e` and `e` in `a`, and

> (7.23.2) `kx` is not convertible to either `iterator` or `const_­iterator`; and [...]

these are used in concert with `a_tran`, which is the shortcut the standard uses for "an associative container when `Compare` has `is_transparent`", to describe the requirements of most (all?) of the extra methods you get when you have `is_transparent` turned on.

So under this, the important part is that your non-key elements actually used actually partition your container with the actual keys stored in the container:

> ```
> a_tran.erase(kx)
> ```

> 122 # Result: `size_­type`

> 123 # Effects: Erases all elements in the container with key `r` such that `!c(r, kx) && !c(kx, r)` is `true`.

what this means is you have to check each and every methods requiements for what it expects.  Count, for example:

> ```
> a_tran.count(ke)
> ```

> 150 # Result: `size_­type`

> 151 # Returns: The number of elements with key `r` such that `!c(r, ke) && !c(ke, r)`.

> 152 # Complexity: log(`a_tran.size()`)+`a_tran.count(ke)`

So here the argument must be `ke`, so the specific value passed in has to be a "nice" partition of the current contents of the associative container.